# Querying 3 collections from firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am using an object called "Documento" to store data in firestore, and then when i retrieve this data i store it in a JSON structure. Now, my problem is that now i have three queries to be done. One that is a schedule, another one is doctor, and the other one is his type. All three of them are stored in different queries, now my schedule needs to have a doctor name from the doctor collection and his type that is in my third collection.

Therefore, i would like to know a way to query them together and merge them into a single object, so i can display my patient information alongside his doctor information, resulting into my schedule, which will go into a HTML.

Heres a screenshot of how my firebase/firestore is structured:

My schedule which needs to have some sort of foreign key
[image: https://imgur.com/a/9lEtjNB]

[image: Structure]

[image: Patient Structure]

[image: Medic Structure]

Then here's how i am retrieving my data from firestore as an object in a JSON structure:

```
  carregarPerfil(){
    var query = firebase.firestore().collection("Usuario")
    var auxint = 0;
    this.dataAux
    let auxString = '[';
    query.where('Documento.nome', '==', 'Merlin').where('Documento.login', '==', 'merlin').get().then(res => {
      res.forEach(item => {

        auxint++;
        auxString += '{"id":"' + item.id + '","Usuario":' + JSON.stringify(item.data()) + '}';
        console.log(item);
        if (res.size != auxint)
          auxString += ', ';
      })
      auxString += ']';
      this.dataJSON = JSON.parse(auxString);
      this.Usuario = this.dataJSON;
      console.log(this.Usuario);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('algum erro ' + err);
    });
}
```

I have tried reading the documentation on firestore, but due to the fact it isn't treating it as a JSON and it doesn't show how to do it using 3 queries step-by-step made it hard for me, therefore i need some help in this.

Comment: You can **chain** the three queries with `then()`, one after the other. As a matter of fact, since the `get()` method is asynchronous and return a promise, you have to wait the promise resolves before being able to use the value(s) returned by the query. You should give much more details on your data structure (i.e. the 3 collections) for the community to be able to help you. Another approach would be to de-normalize your data and, for example, add the doctor's type to the doctor document, reducing the number of queries to 2.

Comment: I have updated the main post with a more detailed picture of my current structure, anyways could you provide an example on how would i chain these queries after handling the promises?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in the agenda Document you have the ID of the three other documents (Especialidade, Medico and Patiente) and you want to get info from these three documents at the end (in one shot)?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i need to do and i can't figure out, I need the nome attribute from Medico, i need the nome attribute from Paciente, and i need the nome from Especialidade, and list them with Agenda data, some sort of foreign key basically, denormalization would take a while since i am not sure if the guy handling would be up for the job

Comment: See my answer. Note that in the answer we are **not** chaining several promises, as we execute them in parallel and not in sequence. On the opposite, we are using `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Yeah, just trying to figure out what caused Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Comment: replace `db` by `firebase.firestore()`. Will adapt the answer

Comment: Amazing! that works perfectly, that was really life saving! Just one question, how can i print the data via string interpolation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180359/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-john-rivers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the trick. Since you want to fetch **in parallel** three documents and since the `get()` method is asynchronous and returns a promise, you need to use `Promise.all()`. Note that the `results` array has the same order than the `promises` array (so first element of `results` is the `especialidade` document, then the `medico`, etc.).

*Note that I've adapted the collection names to english. Just modify in order to use your own collection names. Doc IDs are also to be adapted to yours.*

```
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var promises = []

    var especialidadeQuery = db.collection('specialties').doc('xTWQVLM8O9WRx89LS1Ba').get();
    promises.push(especialidadeQuery);

    var medicoQuery = db.collection('doctors').doc('CP5Gd2UwGyDYqs9eXuGl').get();
    promises.push(medicoQuery);

    var patienteQuery = db.collection('patients').doc('AMZpmX9BOyRlfPQpwfmz').get();
    promises.push(patienteQuery);

    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        results.map(docSnapshot => {
            console.log(docSnapshot.data());
        });
    });
```

---

Note however, that if you just need the names of the patient, doctor and specialty you could very well store these values directly in the agenda document. This mechanism of de-normalization is quite common in the NoSQL database word and allows optimizing the queries (here, 1 instead of 1+3).